# Скорость обработки массива ArrayList. Цикл for и for-each

Tags: java

Решил посмотреть разницу скорости обработки циклов for и for-each.

```
long start,end = 0;        
start = System.currentTimeMillis();  
ArrayList<Long> al = new ArrayList<>();       

for(long a = 0; a < 10000000; a++) { al.add(a);}        
System.out.println("ArrayList size = "+ al.size());  

for(long b : al){end = System.currentTimeMillis();}
System.out.println("Выполнение for-each = " + (end-start)+" mc");        
start = System.currentTimeMillis();

for(long a = 0; a < al.size(); a++) { end = System.currentTimeMillis(); }
System.out.println("Стандартный цикл = " + (end-start)+" mc");
```

Толи я что-то не так написал или скорость реально очень отличается. Получил на выходе:

```
ArrayList size = 10000000
Выполнение for-each = 10616 mc
Стандартный цикл = 475 mc
```

Цифры понятное дело разные, но разница между ними всегда почти в три раза.

Поэтому хочу узнать, выходит что классический цикл в три раза быстрее отрабатывает или допустил ошибку в программе?

Даже если переделать вот так:

```
start = System.currentTimeMillis();
for(long b : al);
end = System.currentTimeMillis();

System.out.println("Выполнение for-each = " + (end-start)+" mc");

start = System.currentTimeMillis();
for(long a = 0; a < al.size(); a++);
end = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Разница все равно получается большая.

Comment: Потому что, в-первом случае вы перебираете элементы массива, во-втором случае вы просто увеличиваете перемеренную a до размера массива.

Comment: Вы тестируете не скорость цикла, а скорость цикла + вызов System.currentTimeMillis(). Так как не известно соотношение цены этих двух вызовов, Ваши рассуждения о "трех разах" не имеют смысла.

Но в любом случае  - обычный цикл прост, а foreach может потребовать копирование объекта.

Comment: Кроме всего прочего, у Вас `start` захватывает заполнение массива как для цикла `for-each`.

Comment: Обратите внимание когда происходит присвоение значений `start`-у

Comment: @AlexKrass О! думаю это главная причина такой разницы.

Comment: `foreach`, между прочим, работает через итератор. `for(Iterator<Long> i = a1.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

В первом куске кода вы после фиксации стартового времени создаете ArrayList, наполняете его в цикле, а после перебираете через for-each на каждой итерации определяя end. А после этого пытаетесь сравнить с скоростью инкремента переменной `a` от 0 до размера ArrayList с опять же определяемой end на каждой итерации. При этом во втором цикле доступ к коллекции не производится. То есть вы измерили скорость выполнения двух циклов с доступом к коллекции а также автоматическим расширением при добавлении элементов в нее и простое перещелкивание переменной. Вы явно пытались сделать не это.

Во втором куске кода уже ближе к истине, но опять не то.

```
for(long a = 0; a < al.size(); a++);
```

Здесь вы пробежались от 0 до размера коллекции, но не получали доступ к её элементам. Измените на следующее:

```
long b;
for(int a = 0; a < al.size(); a++) {
   b = al.get(a);
};
```

Comment: GreyGoblin, такой код не пропускает. Не применим. Доступ к ArrayList можно получить только через for-each..

Comment: Индекс должен быть `int` просто. Второй цикл сделайте таким: `for(int a = 0; a < al.size(); a++)`

Comment: @Kamenev_D прошу прощения, скопировал ваш код, не изменив тип переменной. Поправил ответ.

Comment: @iksuy спасибо. Надо мне не лениться ответы проверять. Ошибиться можно даже в простом коде.

Comment: Сделал так:
        long i ;
        for(long a = 0; a < al.size(); a++){i = al.get((int)a);} 

В результате скорость получается практически одинакова.
Выходит что скорость циклов не сильно отличается.

Comment: @Kamenev_D для ArrayList разницы особенно быть не должно. А вот с LinkedList уже так не прокатит, так как операция доступа по индексу у него происходит последовательно от начала или конца списка(смотря что ближе к индексу), в этом случае перебор через итератор, не важно for each или нет, будет в выигрыше.

Comment: Вопрос можно считать решенным. Всем спасибо за участие и советы.

Comment: P.S: А вот в Андроид этот же код отрабатывает с очень существенной разницей. Классический цикл отрабатывает быстрее.